# Why is the Letter R in R.id red and stopping my project from running

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

(R.id.imageView1) The R at the beginning is Red and stopping my project from running, why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 0):

you must clean your project . in android studio: build->clean.... after that, your project will rebuild automatically and error will be disappear

and in eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys (Ctrl+Shift+L)

Answer (score 0):

The R file for your project is created without errors only when your project is clean of all errors in the resources(res) folder. Check if there are any errors pending in that folder. Once you are done with it , clean your project and you will be good to go